# Insertion of character in cell through clicking

Tags: excel, vba

How to insert a character in Excel cell by simply clicking on it? Clicking again on the cell would remove the character from the cell.

Example:
I have a cell range, A1:A10. If I click on a cell on this range a "X" is inserted on that specific cell, clicking again on it would remove the "X".

Can this be made through a button assigned to a macro? (the button would be assign to a specific cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a cell range, A1:A10. If I click on a cell on this range a "X" is inserted on that specific cell, clicking again on it would remove the "X".

You have to be very careful when you are using `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`. If you do not take care of that in the code then the code will fire whenever there is a double click. Also use `Cancel = True` appropriately else you may get undesired results.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, _
                                        Cancel As Boolean)

    '~~> Check if the double click happened in Range A1:A10
    '~~> Also notice the placement of `Cancel = True`   
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check if the cell is empty
        If Len(Trim(Target)) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = "X"
            Cancel = True
        '~~> Check if the cell already has X. This is to ensure that
        '~~> the cell is not cleared if the user has typed something
        '~~> else in the cell.
        ElseIf UCase(Trim(Target)) = "X" Then
            Target.ClearContents
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use double click to enter/remove value. If you're ok with using double click..then here's the code for that:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If IsEmpty(Target.Cells) Then

Target.Cells.Value = "x"

Else: Target.Cells.Clear

End If

Cancel = True

End Sub
```

The code needs to be placed in ThisWorkbook object

Answer (score -1):

This does not seem like a good approach. Why not use dropdowns? 
Go to Data->Validation select a list. You can either select your list of options from an Excel range or simply specify the list like this "Item1;Item2" etc.

Using any VBA will prevent the usage Undo function in Excel meaning - any time a macro executes in Excel all you undo history is cleared. This is very inconvenient when making changes.